# Como despliego mensajes de colores en la consola del navegador?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

actualmente estaba trabajando y me encontre esto en la consola de un sitio web.

Quisiera poderlo replicar para mis trabajos pero no se como seria.

Adjunto la imagen de la evidencia, he intentado investigar al respecto pero no he encontrado informacion precisa para replicar esto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias

Comment: https://dev.to/capscode/style-console-log-like-a-pro-8mp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo pasando los estilos como segundo parámetro a la función `log.` Pasando `%c` antes del mensaje a mostrar:

```
  console.log(
  "%c¡Hola Mundo!",
  "background-color:red;color:#fff;padding: 5px 10px;"
   );
```

Puedes ver más sobre la consola de `JavaScript`
[Consola JS](https://lenguajejs.com/javascript/introduccion/consola-de-javascript/)

Aquí un ejemplo [condesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-breeze-jqzk8x?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: Agrega que tiene info, error, warn, etc.